# RxJS node-oauth simple get request fails

Tags: node.js, oauth, rxjs

Dealing with a simple(relatively) RxJS demo/test code that makes a Twitter Api call and a MongoDB request and zipping them into a single observable.

To be able to make a Twitter Api call you need to be authenticated via Oauth. I've found [node-oauth](https://github.com/ciaranj/node-oauth) library to auth node request:

```
var oauth = new OAuth.OAuth(
    'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token',
    'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token',
    'key',
    'secret',
    '1.0A',
    null,
   'HMAC-SHA1'
);
```

Then I'm creating a new Observable with `Oauth get` method to get places from Twitter:

```
var twitterStream = Rx.Observable.fromNodeCallback(oauth.get)('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/trends/place.json?id=23424977',
    'access-token',
    'token');
```

Another stream from MongoDB:

```
Rx.Node.fromStream(Order.find().stream());
```

Final step to zip them:

```
var getNewList = Rx.Observable
    .zip(flickrStream, orderStream, function(user, order) {
        return {user: user, order: order};
    });

getNewList.subscribe(function(response) {
    // render `response`
    console.log(response);
});
```

Despite code seems Ok to me when I execute it via Node the message below is printed to the console:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method '_performSecureRequest'
at exports.OAuth.get (/.../node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth.js:487:15)
at /.../node_modules/rx/dist/rx.all.js:5504:14
```

It's possible that I've done sth. wrong when creating new Observable with Twitter request. Additionally; I've tested codes individually within making Twitter call without RxJS and MongoDB query and those are working without any problems. Also changing `fromNodeCallback` to `fromCallback` didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either supply the `context` parameter (see [documentation](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/fromnodecallback.md)) or bind the context for `get`:

```
Rx.Observable.fromNodeCallback(oauth.get.bind(oauth))
```

or

```
Rx.Observable.fromNodeCallback(oauth.get, oauth)
```